# JS code to click multiple icon present on Webpage which opens new tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

On a webpage i have 9 icons which has same class. I want to write a JS code so that all 9 icons web page opens up automatically. I thought below code will do the trick but it just clicks first icon and stops as a new page opens up.

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.ClassName');
a.forEach(btn => btn.click());
```

is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Provide some example code.

Answer (score 0):

No even if you were to force the `metaKey` on the dispatched [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) event like so...

```js
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { metaKey: true }))
```

The browser (at least Chrome) *will* open a new tab but focus the new tab not the existing one.

The same happens when you use [`window.open`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) with `target='_blank'` such as...

```js
window.open('https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp', '_blank')
```

> There may be a way that I'm not aware of but this is not possible from what I understand.

Comment: thanks for the response. Now as i dont have any option to click the buttons using JS, i am wondering if i can achieve the same using python. Not sure if its a crazy idea but m thinking that i will click the first button using the python code then using python GUI automation i will open the tab 1 again then click button 2 and then again click tab 1 using python GUI...will do this in a loop. Hope it works